# ignore php $variable what is in $value array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I understand the title isn't the best one to describe what I am trying to do but that is because I am stumped and do not know what to call this method.

I have built a status system and when someone replies to a status their username is stored in an array for that status so I can have a list of everyone who has replied to that status so when someone else replies everyone who has replied receives a new notification saying that some has replied to that status.

Now the problem is when someone replies to the status for the 2nd time they receive a notification saying that they have replied to the status and that is not ideal at all as they know they have replied because they replied to it.

I have been looking around for a few hours now and can't seem to find what I am looking for and I have tried a few methods.

Here is my code

```
if ($follower_array != ""){
    $follower_array2 = explode(",", $follower_array);
    foreach ($follower_array2 as $key => $value) { 

     mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO notifications(username, initiator, app, note, date_time)
                    VALUES('$value','$log_username','$app','$note',NOW())"); }
}
```

This is what I have tried. I just want to add that the username that I wish to ignore is inside of this variable `$log_username`

```
if ($follower_array != ""){
        $follower_array2 = explode(",", $follower_array);
        foreach ($follower_array2 as $key => $value) {

        $log_username != $value;

         mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO notifications(username, initiator, app, note, date_time)
                    VALUES('$value','$log_username','$app','$note',NOW())"); }
    }
```

Method 2:

```
 if ($follower_array != ""){
                $follower_array2 = explode(",", $follower_array);
                foreach ($follower_array2 as $key => $value) {

                $log_username != $key;

                 mysqli_query($db_conx, "INSERT INTO notifications(username, initiator, app, note, date_time)
                    VALUES('$value','$log_username','$app','$note',NOW())"); }
            }
```

I need to ignore the `$log_username` within the array so that the person who is posting the reply doesn't receive a notification about themselves posting a reply to the status.

I am still coming to terms with php so I do apologize about my failed nooby attempts!

If someone could help me out I would appreciate it very much.

Thank you for your time

p.s. the notifications get posted to the database so that side of things is fine it is just ignoring the person who is submitting the reply I wish to ignore.

Comment: Is `$log_username != $value;` actual code you're trying to use? What are you trying to achieve with that? It's a boolean comparison, so will yield a value, but that value will never be stored anywhere.

Comment: Can you please expand the THIS IS THE QUERY part?

Comment: THIS IS THE QUERY part is just the MySQL INSERT part of the script e..g database table names and stuff.

Comment: `$log_username != $value;` probably isn't proper code as I have been shooting in the dark because of the fact I can't actually seem to find what I am looking for.

Comment: in MYSQL QUERY Part, if you say **nd stuff** it too complicatd as mysql query can be to insert or to select, which one are you  doing do specify. & the major part of your program depends on that

Comment: I have added the query now

Answer (score 1):

if i understood your question then the solution is .

i am assuming when some one posts a replay the script is pushing him/her username into an array .

like this

```
if($commentPosted){
   array_push($follower_array , $username);
}
```

if i am right then change your code like this .

```
if($commentPosted) {
 if(in_array($username , $follower_array)) {
   array_push($follower_array , $username);
 }
}
```

Comment: I am saving the user in a array onto the database when they have replied yes. The problem I am having now is when I get the array from the database so I can send a notification to everyone who has replied to that status but because the user who has just posted the new reply is in that array they also receive a notification and this is what I am trying to stop because there is no need for them to recieve a notification if they are the ones that posted the reply

Comment: you need to store theme in a separate table . or filter that array you getting from database ..

Comment: ok thank you. I did start think I would have to do that. I believe I have a method in my head that will work but didn't want to rewrite if I didn't have to but looks like I do not to worry. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 0):

Your program won't work most likely, as the $value which will be stored in client side and not in server side. so anyways when a user open this app, he need to load the already comment users from the database, which is missing from your code I guess.

By the way the way you are doing this operation is not correct.

---

You need to store the list of unique commenters in database only and check for uniqueness while storing.

Comment: I have all the users that have replied on the database in an array. The array that contains all of the usernames is in `$follower_array`

Comment: There are no arrays in database up to my knowledge. U may store those name in a list i.e rows of usernames.

Comment: in the database it is like this user1,user2,user3,user4,user5,user6,user7 and so on.